# Create Standby database using SE

Tags: oracle

We are on 11.2.0.1.I have been trying to create a Manual Standby database using Standard Edition.

Although at this point its more like an incomplete recovery.

This is wat i did

```
Create Standby control file on the source

Backup source(db+arc).

Restore on target.(Followed pretty much the standard RMAN restore procedures)
```

Am able to mount the instance and apply the most recent ARC generated on the source.But when I try to  open I get the below error

```
<span><span><span><span><span><span>  
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================  
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============  
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================  
RMAN-03002: failure of alter db command at 03/21/2014 14:02:12  
ORA-01666: control file is for a standby database</span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

This is what i see on my alert log

```
<span><span><span><span><span><span>  
ORA-279 signalled during: alter database recover logfile '/u03/oracle_recovery/flash_recovery_area/XX/1_11478_723733449.arc'...  
alter database recover cancel  
Media Recovery Canceled  
Completed: alter database recover cancel  
Fri Mar 21 09:07:25 2014  
alter database open resetlogs  
ORA-1666 signalled during: alter database open resetlogs...  
Fri Mar 21 09:07:57 2014  
alter database open resetlogs</span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Reading up on some posts over the internet I tried to open the DB in RO mode

```
alter database open read only  
Beginning standby crash recovery.  
Serial Media Recovery started  
Managed Standby Recovery starting Real Time Apply  
Media Recovery Waiting for thread 1 sequence 11479  
FAL[client]: Error fetching gap sequence, no FAL server specified  
Fri Mar 21 09:11:21 2014  
Standby crash recovery need archive log for thread 1 sequence 11479 to continue.  
Please verify that primary database is transporting redo logs to the standby database.  
Wait timeout: thread 1 sequence 11479  
Standby crash recovery aborted due to error 16016.  
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xx/xx/trace/xx_ora_21943.trc:  
ORA-16016: archived log for thread 1 sequence# 11479 unavailable  
Recovery interrupted!  
Completed standby crash recovery.  
Signalling error 1152 for datafile 1!  
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xx/xx/trace/xx_ora_21943.trc:  
ORA-10458: standby database requires recovery  
ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup
```

I understand that it is requesting the next archive sequence 11479.This is not yet generated on the source.

Can anyone tell me why 'Open resetlogs' failed in the first place ?

Is this the behaviour when we create a 'Standby' control file ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is some misunderstanding here.

Your alert log shows that you were trying to use Data Guard features, this is clearly not a manual standby.

A manual standby is a copy of the "primary" database *continuously* rolled forward *manually* with the archive logs from the "primary" database. 
You transfer the archivelogs with OS commands, e.g. scp or rsync. Then you periodically register the archivelogs and recover the database with RMAN or SQL*Plus user managed recovery, but definitely not the Data Guard Media Recovery Process.
Data Guard is not involved at all, so there is no need for a standby controlfile, just a regular controlfile.